# Is it possible to change the inequality behaviour of interp1 when using 'previous' or 'next'

Tags: matlab

Consider as examples:

```
interp1([0, 1], [2, 3], 0 , 'previous')
interp1([0, 1], [2, 3], 0 , 'next')
```

which produces

```
ans =

     2


ans =

     2
```

That is, in each respective case it finds the value in `[0, 1]` closest to and not exceeding 0 (respectively closest to and not below 0), then returns the corresponding value of `[2,3]`. I would like to change the second condition to "closest to and above 0", that is, it should return the same results as:

```
interp1([0, 1], [2, 3], 0.1 , 'previous')
interp1([0, 1], [2, 3], 0.1 , 'next')
```

which gives

```
ans =

     2


ans =

     3
```

In this case this works as `0.1` is a value in between `[0, 1]`.

Comment: Define a small tolerance and substract it to your `[0 , 1]` vector. Not a very nice hack but you'll get the expected behaviour.